# Радио России

Tags: кавычки

Нужно ли ставить в кавычки? Дали интервью Радио России

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут надо выяснить, что является названием организации. Это может быть просто радио России, как, например, радио Казахстана или радио Саратова. Но это же может быть и названием - "Радио России". Определите, о чем конкретно идет речь.

Comment: Это часть названия. "Радио России - Саратов"
Я так поняла, что кавычки нужны